# I literally visit Stack Overflow daily but the visited calendar says that I am missing days

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, consecutive-days

The title explains it all. Visit my profile.

[image]

Comment: Did you visit the site once daily from Earth's **UTC** 00:00 - 23:59 (and not in the moon's timezone)? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66526/consecutive-days-is-flawed https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55406/shouldnt-consecutive-days-measure-from-midnight-to-midnight-in-the-users-time

Comment: Also make sure to not open Stack Overflow in a cached state; visit another link or so to make sure some network traffic exists.

Comment: Also we can't actually see that calendar on your profile.

Comment: @AndréKool the calendar is private for each person. You can see your own calendar, but not anyone else's. At least for us mortals - mods might be able to.

Comment: What do you actually do when you "visit"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Look for rep changes or notifications.

Comment: @Zoe: moderators are able to see the calendar.